# type class and casting to sObject

Tags: apex

I've seen this type of Salesforce idiom a few times in code I'm looking at, and it seems like it's for dynamic apex. What's the function of the Type class, and what's kind of going on here?

```
Type childType = Type.forName(sObject_string_name);

 SObject newChildRecord = (sObject)childType.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This allows code to be written that isn't tied at compile time to a particular type. That need comes up rarely in most Apex code.

`Type.forName` will check that the type is available and return a `Type` value that can then be used to create a new instance of the object. The down-cast to `SObject` is needed because `newInstance` returns the base type `Object` not `SObject`. This:

```
Type t = Type.forName('Contact');
SObject c = (SObject) t.newInstance();
```

produces the same result as:

```
SObject c = new Contact();
```

The convenience of referencing SObject fields via the simple `sob.Field` syntax is lost; instead [sob.get('Field')](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get) and [sob.put('Field', value)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_put) and similar methods have to be used and compile time checking (including of field type) is lost.

Another use of `Type.forName` is to allow extension points to be created in packaged code and for classes outside of that code to be created and used by the packaged code. This is described early in the [Type Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_type.htm) documentation.